# iOS Xcode Simulator in use

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

When I develop iOS application, I run many other projects.
But at that time, I got an message from XCODE : Simulator in use.

So I have closed my simulator that has run a project, and run another project again and i repeat this behavior.

Very uncomfortable! Is there anyone help me being comfortable to run projects free?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the launched project, click on stop, find the project you want to run and run it. Without closing any project or the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem happen to me recently.  I had two projects open in Xcode, neither of which was running on the iOS Simulator. When I tried to start a Simulator run of one, I got the message "Simulator in use" even though nothing was running on the Simulator. I had to close both Xcode and Simulator and re-open Xcode before I could get Simulator to work.